# Remove meassge-id exchange

Tags: email, exchange

we are planing to remove message-IDs from all incomming mails on our Exchange server.

The reason is our SPAM-Filter which redelivers content-filtered mails with the same message-ID as the orignal mail and the Exchange then dicards them with DUPLICATEDELIVER.

Can the general removal of message-IDs be problematic in the long run or is it safe to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My personal judgement in this case would be to keep `Message-ID` and find out other way how to solve it (not handle it as duplicated).

---

From the "just" delivery point of view the `Message-ID` header is not crucial. The message will be delivered even without it. It is optional but expected in current mail systems. It will be the most probably generated if missing.

The e-mail service in principle is just "single message" design so nothing like conversation exists naturally (create, send, deliver, read [,delete]). The "problem" may happen with additional features like showing the e-mails in threads (not correctly paired).

There are few more headers which directly works with `Massage-ID` header like `References` or `In-Reply-To`.